# Understanding Job and job table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jobs, laravel-5.1

I am using [`job`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues) in laravel5.1.

First I created one table `job` by running artisan command as follows.

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate // You forgot this
```

I have written `job class` as well,

```
php artisan make:job RecordAttendanceJob --queued
class RecordAttendanceJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue {
 -------------
 ------------- 
}
```

And I `dispatch` this from controller as follows and working fine,

```
  $job = (new RecordAttendanceJob($attArray));
  $this->dispatch($job);
```

Here my doubt is,

- Why using that job table, I found always empty that job table?
- What is the best way to notify success/failure of jobs to user later?
- I found following method as well,`Queue::push(new RecordAttendanceJob($attArray))` . What is the differnce between this and about `dispatch` job? which is better method?

Comment: In addition to the official laravel 5.1 docs, I'd suggest you also read this article: http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-about-queues I think it explains pretty well how queues and jobs work, including the various queue drivers. As the job table is always empty in your case, I'd guess you're still using the default sync driver, which processes items immediately and synchronously

Comment: @KristofM I have updated config and now getting error `DOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away........` system trying to insert junk value to table `job`

Comment: @KristofM the link seems broken

Answer (score 0):

For a notify when a job failed add the function failed to your job class that method will run when the job failed. (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#failed-job-events)